# PHP Carbon Add Month But Fixed Date

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a fixed date, but the month keep increment

```
$now = Carbon::now(); // 2019-03-12
```

I already try using `Carbon::now()->addMonth(1)` but its just adding one month and not fixed the date.
what i expected from the output is 2019-04-25 the date is fixed to **25**

Can i `addMonth(1)` but fixed the date to **25** ??

Comment: `25`? And how on earth it is `25`?

Comment: I just want to fixed the day to 25, but adding +1 month

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$date = Carbon::now(); // 2019-03-12
$date->day(25)->addMonth(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand too well, but maybe you are looking for this:

```
$date = Carbon::create(2019, 4, 25);
```

Comment: can i just edit the addMonth(1) but the date i want fixed to 25 ??

Comment: Do you mean this? `Carbon::now()->addMonth(1)->day(25)`

Comment: Thank you so much. iam very newbie on php so... you save my day bro

Comment: i have an input and when user add date i want to add month to it not using Carbon::now() ;